# easier way to debug nodejs than placing a breakpoint in each .then

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently moved to work with `nodejs` while this may not be necessarily a `nodejs` specific, right now when I `debug` with `intellij` my `nodejs` app I do this:

```
somePromise.then(function(success) {
  logger.info('I have to put a breakpoint here');
});
```

so my flow has many (out of my control I inherited that project), many `.then` and i cannot debug the whole `request` as one piece.  ultimately I would like for debug purposes only to be able to put a `breakpoint` only at the request `route` entry point, and then continue debugging with `intellij` `F7/F8 stepin/stepover` and its really really difficult that I need to put a breakpoint in any `.then` any help on this? my life is really difficult these days.

I know I should not use `debugging` too much, logging is better, but this is true life here I have a project which does not include all logging I want and I cant add them I need to use the `debugging` as a mechanism to understand the flow, the code is not clear, and sometimes it helps reproducing an troubleshooting a problem this way, so please kindly do not suggest me not to debug because I really do want to debug this time.

Comment: Whoever said you shouldn't use debugging "too much" better have an explanation for "too much" since debugging is a normal activity and logging can't in practice replace it always.

Comment: [I was introduced in the past to this practice (its a link)](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dont%20use%20debugging)

Comment: "Linus Torvalds, the creator of Linux, does not use a debugger.
Robert C. Martin, one of the inventors of agile programming, thinks that debuggers are a wasteful timesink.
John Graham-Cumming hates debuggers.
Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike wrote that stepping through a program less productive than thinking harder and adding output statements and self-checking code at critical places. Kernighan once wrote that the most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled with judiciously placed print statements."  http://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/21/i-do-not-use-a-debugger/

Comment: Have you tried node-inspector? https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: @LarryTurtis nope but i just read its readme and correct me if i'm wrong but i don't see such a feature

Comment: You can't step through promises AFAIK because they are inherently asynchronous. What you could do is modify the promise library and insert some logging code in the `then` function. If you're using kriskowal/q, for example, around here: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L839

Comment: @LarryTurtis thanks what about updating tghe promise library to be synchronous just for local debugging to see flow.